# "Заниматься любовью"

Tags: стилистика

Честно говоря, меня очень коробит выражение "заниматься любовью". Любовь — это чувство, как им можно заниматься. Это все равно, что "заниматься надеждой", например. А как оценивается это выражение с точки зрения русского языка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это разговорное (не литературное) выражение. Из толкового словаря: 
Любовь 
...

**2.**
Чувство горячей сердечной склонности, влечение к лицу другого пола. Жениться по любви. Первая л. Страстная, пылкая л. Девичья л. К ним пришла л. Вечная л. * Любовь ещё, быть может, в душе моей угасла не совсем (Пушкин). Совет да любовь
(пожелание жениху и невесте, молодым супругам). // **Разг.**
Половые отношения, интимная связь. Быть в любви с кем-л. Крутить л. с кем-л. Заниматься любовью. Прижить в любви ребёнка
(родить от внебрачной любовной связи).

Answer (score 4):

Калька с английского (даже американского).
Стало набирать популярность в годы хиппи, одним из девизов которых было "Make love, nо war". Как и всякий англицизм встречает довольно сильное сопротивление со стороны наиболее консервативных носителей русского языка. Но в общем-то как разговорное уже вошло в лексикон и бороться бесполезно.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, это эвфемизм, так как слово "секс" звучит более грубо и приземленно. Хотя в выражении имеется в виду именно это (по-крайней мере, в русском варианте).

Answer (score 0):

Согласна с выражением "любовью не занимаются", поскольку это чувство, а не действие. Занимаюсь чтением, рукоделием, спортом, чаепитием и т.д. А любовь, радость, горесть, боль, печаль, тоску... — ощущаю, чувствую.